# Installing TWRP on a locked OnePlus One without wiping data

Tags: rooting, fastboot, twrp

I am trying to upgrade my OPO's operating system from CyanogenMod to the latest nightly version of LineagOS.

As a first step, I tried installing TWRP, by executing from my shell the command:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

But I got the following message:

```
FAILED (remote:         Device not unlocked cannot flash or erase)
```

I read in a few places that I should first unlock my device by executing the command `fastboot oem unlock`, but that it is going to erase all my data.

Is it true? Is there a way to avoid the erasure of the data?

Comment: How did you install CM without unlocking BL?

Comment: @iBug Probably not CyanogenMod, but CyanogenOS - which was indeed preloaded on some international OPOs.

Comment: Yes, what I have is CyanogenOS that was installed initially

Answer (score 0):

NO. Period.

If you want to unlock the bootloader erasure is inevitable. You can make a backup, but I'm not sure it'll be restored. However what is the point when you flash a custom ROM you'll need to wipe data in that case anyway. However you can move media to SD card pull it out and unlock bootloader (Make sure the SD card isn't encrypted).

Comment: Thank you! I became much more complex than what I thought at first. Even copying a gallery accumulated in more than 2 years to the computer is a nightmare - you wait long time just for Windows to compute how long it is going to take to copy the directory... I've finally gave up for now

Comment: Transfer all media to SD card and pull it out (make sure it's not encrypted) and unlock bootloader. Or you can use Google drive, Mega or some other cloud storage to do backup online.